# Redirect not loading CSS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have this redirect set to redirect all pages to the maintenance page:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$
RewriteRule $ /maintenance.php [L]
```

However, it's not loading the CSS (located in `/assets/css/stylesheet.css`). How can I have it load the CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a weird way of thinking but here's a solution for your example

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:assets/css/|maintenance\.php$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /maintenance.php [L]
```

Note: you should not do it that way (bad for search engines indexing pages when you're on maintenance)

A better way of doing it (following your idea) is to send a `503` HTTP code to tell crawlers/users your site is under maintenance

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:assets/css/|maintenance\.php$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /maintenance.php [R=503,L]
```

Comment: How would you suggest it be done that would be considered a good way for SEO? I'm returning a 503 header on the page it's redirected to.